# Regarding VPS on ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, vps

How can I create a VPS on Ubuntu ? I want to create a vps on Ubuntu but can not understand so please give me suggestion and tell me that can i create it by any software if yes then tell me software name.

Answer (score 1):

What is a VPS *to you*? Might seem like an odd question but there are numerous interpretations on what'll be best based on what you're actually doing. Here are a few examples:

- If you just want another copy of Ubuntu to play with, use desktop virtualisation software like VirtualBox or VMWare. This will also support things like Windows. These are generally the best option for graphical virtual installs.
- If you want a more application-level containerisation so you can deploy multiple discrete nodes, you probably want something like `lxc` or Docker. This shares system resources a lot more than a "real" virtualisation method so there's less overhead and generally better performance, but less separation. Docker is something else to look at in this area. OpenVZ is a bit like this too.
- If you want to deploy permanent and highly separated installs of various linux distributions inside Ubuntu, you can use XEN's dom0 (or kvm, or something similar) as a hypervisor.
- If you just want a web server installed in your desktop version of Ubuntu, you don't need any virtualisation. All the packages that are available to Ubuntu Server are available to Ubuntu Desktop (and all its flavours). Just install and configure the applications as you would on a Server install.